# ASP.DLL memory leak (or something) forcing constant restart of w3wp

Tags: iis, asp-classic

We've been struggling with this for the past 12 or so months. We think it's due to either one or two apps that are leaking memory or a large amount of leaks that have finally accumulated over years of programming in classic ASP. We've begun the conversion to ASP.NET but we still have a large number of apps in classic.

We've tried changing how IIS restarts, depending on CPU and memory usage and we've tried to clean up some processes. We've installed multiple analytical tools to be able to track exactly where it's coming from to no avail.

Just today we were able to finally track down a more detail error message, "Detected possible blocking or leaked critical section at asp!g Template cache+88 owned by thread 72 in W3WP". It also states that "ASP.DLL is currently holding a Critical Section Lock on ASP template cache manager...".

[image] ([View larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gHgI.png).)

So. Is there any tool that will help track where our leak is coming from? Or maybe a better way to restart this before it freezes our whole web process?

I appreciate your time!

Comment: Which version of IIS?  Is everything running in the same app pool?

Comment: @murisonc IIS 7.  We have multiple app pools but only one fails.  That one has most of our older classic asp pages.

Comment: Are you and Dan Biss coworkers?  http://serverfault.com/questions/645645/asp-dll-is-currently-holding-a-critical-section-lock-on-asp-template-cache

Comment: `We've been struggling with this for the past 12 or so months` - Not to be `that` guy but for $250.00 US you could have opened a support case with Microsoft PSS and had this solved. How much do you think you spent in man hours struggling to resolve it over a 12 month period?

Comment: I would try to narrow it down to a single app by putting each of those older classic asp apps on it's own app pool.  Then do what joeqwerty mentioned.